# Share Laravel Session With Node.js / Socket.io Server

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, jwt

My question is simple. I need to share the laravel session with my nodejs (socket.io) server securely. The reason I need to share the session to the nodejs server is because I use a nodejs sql library to do query's instead of POST request to the laravel server. I tried JWT auth for the socket.io but I can't find any information on how secure JWT is. Any help?

Comment: Redis. You use redis for your laravel sessions. You can secure JWT in many ways. However, for your purposes, you may as well use the `laravel-echo-server` package with laravel's broadcasting and notification systems to avoid all this unnecessary ovferhead.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I do use redis for my sessions, how do you secure the JWT using redis?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is use JWT with a solid nodejs lib to validate the jwt token.